# Flex4 List ItemRenderer children and Events

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a custom item renderer that im using in a List. There is a CheckBox and a ColorPicker in the item renderer. I have created my own custom event classes for these two items and they are not bubbling their events.

You can also click the item in the list, I have 3 listeners attached to the list, I don't want the list item handler firing when children of the list get clicked, how do I do this?

Extract below:

```
     protected function updateList():void
  {
   var proxy:ApplicationDataProxy = ApplicationDataProxy(facade.retrieveProxy(ApplicationDataProxy.NAME));
   list.addEventListener(CustomColorEvent.UPDATED_COLOR, colorClickHandler);
   list.addEventListener(CustomMenuEvent.CHECK_CLICKED, checkClickHandler);
   list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
   list.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(FlightItemRenderer);
   list.dataProvider = proxy.flightsList;
  }

  protected function colorClickHandler(event:CustomColorEvent):void
  {
   sendNotification(ApplicationFacade.UPDATE_COLOR, {id:event.data, color:event.color});
  }

  protected function checkClickHandler(event:CustomMenuEvent):void
  {
   sendNotification(ApplicationFacade.SHOW_FLIGHT, {id:event.data, visible:event.visible});
  }

  protected function clickHandler(event:Event):void
  {
   // also gets fired from colours and checkbox, BUT I DON'T WANT IT TO!!!
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click listener to your item renderer and check the event.target property to see if it was the checkbox that was clicked on, if it is you can call [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29). Here is a a very simple example, no other listeners for MouseEvent.CLICK will be fired.

```
<s:List>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:CheckBox click="checkbox1_clickHandler(event)" />
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        protected function checkbox1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                        {
                            //You could also add this click listener
                            //to the renderer itself if you need to do
                            //something when the checkbox is clicked
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just what I was looking for, never used this before but was aware of it.